# Getting the first child of the next element in the Dom Tree and focusing on it

Tags: javascript, dom

### EDIT - Question updated.

I have a function that when an input reaches its maxlength, it selects the next input ready for more text.

Each of these input boxes are wrapped within an input-container. However when trying the following code, I receive this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

It seems as if it isn't finding the parent of the current element, and therefore isn't able to select the next node.

What am I missing here?

**Snippet**

```js
function prepareInputs() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onkeyup = function() {
      if (this.value.length == 4) {
        this.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].focus();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group input-group-lg col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PART 1" maxlength="4">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group-lg col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PART 2" maxlength="4">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group-lg col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PART 3" maxlength="4">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group-lg col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PART 4" maxlength="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess your code works fine? https://jsfiddle.net/5cmjk5jw/

Comment: looks also fine to me, what's the matter?

Comment: You need to show us your html code? Are those input elements really next to each other?

Comment: @Tresdin You're right, they weren't. Apparently I'm half asleep today. Question updated with new problem.

Comment: @Lewis I think my answer might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because there is indeed no next siblings of `input` elements. Your code should be written like this.

```
  //convert nodeList to array
  var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'));

  inputs.forEach(function(input,i){
    input.onkeyup = function() {

      if (this.value.length != input.maxLength) {
        return;
      }
      var nextInput = inputs[i + 1];
      if(nextInput){
        nextInput.focus();
      }
    }
  });
```